# list of numbers outputting multi digit numbers separately

Tags: python, list, numbers

```
angles = []
angles += raw_input("Enter an angle: ")
angles += raw_input("Enter another angle: ")
angles += raw_input("Enter another angle: ")

hyp = max(angles)
print angles
print hyp
```

when I put in values (20,50,25)

it prints

```
Enter an angle: 20
Enter another angle: 50
Enter another angle: 25
['2', '0', '5', '0', '2', '5']
['2', '0', '5', '0', '2', '5']
5
```

What am I doing wrong? I want it to put 20,50, and 25 into angles and have max(angles) give me the largest number 50 in this case.

Comment: `+=` operator actually calls `list.extend`, which appends each item of the iterable(string here) to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
angles.append(raw_input("Enter an angle: "))
```

The + sign between two lists (in this case your string is considered to be a list of characters) concatenates the two lists. This is not what you want to do. You need to APPEND and not CONCATENATE the new string to the previous list.

If strings could not be considered as a list of characters, you would get an error, because you cannot add (+) a list and a string. However, python implicitly treats your string as a list and gives you a result - this can be very useful, but in your case, it is not the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

use `list.append` method:-

```
angles = []
angles.append(raw_input("Enter an angle: "))
angles.append(raw_input("Enter another angle: "))
angles.append(raw_input("Enter another angle: "))

print angles

what you are doing

>>>angles = []
>>>angles = angles + raw_input("Enter an angle: ")

now look 

>>>l = []
>>>l += 'anything'  #adding iterable at the end of list like `l.extend('anything')`
>>>l
['a', 'n', 'y', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `+` operator use `[]`:

```
>>> a +=[raw_input("enter angel:")]
enter angel:20
>>> a
['20']
>>> a +=[raw_input("enter angel:")]
enter angel:60
>>> a
['20', '60']
```

as other given `append` you can use that too

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = []
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list +=  'abcd'
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> my_list +=  (1,2,3,4)
>>> my_list.extend(list('python'))
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
>>> my_list +=  1234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
# In case of dictionary it will extend keys of dictionary.
>>> my_list += my_dict
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'key2', 'ke1']
```

The `+=` operator extends any `sequence`(which are `iterable`) provided to it.

```
>>> angles = []
>>> angles.append(raw_input("Enter an angle: "))
Enter an angle: 20
>>> angles.append(raw_input("Enter an angle: "))
Enter an angle: 50
>>> angles.append(raw_input("Enter an angle: "))
Enter an angle: 25
>>> angles
['20', '50', '25']
```

You should use `append` built-in function to add element to list.

```
append(...)
    L.append(object) -- append object to end
```